# Adding Screenshots

Tags: discussion

I have a question about identifying a vehicle, I am trying to ask this in the car maintenance section but when I try to upload a picture I get this error

[image]

What am I doing wrong???? I have seen loads of people upload screens of movies and TV shows to this forum (Movies & TV). Is there a way to get the pictures past the auto censor or is it just because of the forum I am in?

Answer (score 1):

Issues relating to the stackexchange platform in general can be asked on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  I don't think this is a particular issue to the mechanics site.

There are a number of similar error messages reported on meta.stackoverflow, some relating to specific browsers, some relating to browser plugins, and one that indicates its due to the size of the image being larger than Imgur (the image host) allows. This last one seems to be the most likely for you.  Is the image you are uploading large?

Comment: Yeah relatively,  I will look at shrinking it and try again. Thanks.

Comment: So now we are competing with main meta ;)